# Closing A Page in WPF and clearing cache

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, frame

I have a tab control page which I navigate to from a different page. when I close the tab control page, and closing all the tab items which each holds a different page as their content, I want that when I reopen the tab control page, the pages withing the tab items to be initialized from scratch.

This is my current setup:

**App.Xaml.cs:**

```
public TabsControlPage tabsControlPage; //initialized elsewhere
```

**TabsControlPage.xaml:**

```
<Page x:Class="TestProject.Views.TabsControlPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
      xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
      mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignHeight="1080" d:DesignWidth="1920"
      Title="TabsControlPage" Name="TabsControl">

    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem  x:Name="TestTab" IsEnabled="False">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Page>
```

**TabsControlPage:**

```
using TestProject.Views;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestProject.Views
{
    public partial class TabsControlPage : Page
    {
        public TabsControlPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestTab.Content = new Frame
            {
                Source = new Uri("Views/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
            };
        }
        private void CloseTabsPage()
        {
            TestTab.Content = null;
            ((App)Application.Current).tabsControlPage.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

At this state when I call the `CloseTabsPage()`, the TestPage is loading only when the application first starts.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your issue. Why do you have a page field in `App.xaml.cs` and antother frame in `TestTab`? What is `TestTab`?

Comment: I have the page field in order to have one object that I can reference to for non-static methods from other pages. Is there a better way? 
I have updated my question with reproducible example.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You don't need this reference. The Page class already provides a NavigationService reference that you can use. [Page.NavigationService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples)

Comment: My question is how to close the frame opened in TestTab in such a way that when I close the TabsControlPage and reopen it, all the variables, including static ones in the TestPage will be loaded from scratch.
With regards to the reference, when I try to use TabsControlPage.NavigationService it returns the error of "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Page.NavigationService'".